# Android calculator with button click

Tags: android, button, methods, android-edittext, calculated-field

I am trying to calculate a field named lblAnswer by adding values txtA + txtB. I am fairly new to the android development world and would like to know what is the best way of going about this. I have already added the necessarily edit fields to the GUI. I am now working in the java file to try and create the method. This method has been named doCalc. Here is what I have thus far.

```
public void doCalc() 
{
    lblAnswer = txtA + txtB;
}
```

It has been suggested that I add more code here is the full code. Thank you for that suggestion.

Here is the Java File.

```
      package com.example.wattsprofessional;

     import android.app.Activity;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.view.Menu;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}


public void doCalc() 
{
    lblAnswer = txtA + txtB;
    Double.parseDouble(txtA.getText().toString());
    lblAnswer.setText"t
}
```

and here is the xml file.

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
              tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
           android:id="@+id/txtA"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
             android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Write Here"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtB"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtA"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtA"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Second Here"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/calculate" 
    android:onClick="doCalc"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblAnswer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what problems are you having exactly? for all we know things are going well without a hitch. I can't give you a *best* way, but what i'd do is make all my calculations separate methods that take parameters and then return a value.

Comment: thank you for the quick reply. Well when I look at the actual method you see above, the lblAnswer = txtA + txtB; has an error line underneath it. It states " Cannot be resolved to a variable" This is the error message for all three. I'm not sure where I am messing up .

Comment: You need to declare them as global variables, then initialize them in `onCreate()`.

Comment: perhaps it's best you provide more code. as Dare has said, have you called declared these values as `ints` or `doubles` or whatever formats you'd like to wield?

Comment: @Dare.  Please read and understand what a global variable is.  It is not what you are suggesting.

Comment: A big guess, but looking at this line, `lblAnswer = txtA + txtB;`, suggests that you are coming from VB, and probably not VB.NET since VB has "default" properties for text boxes.  The equivalent would be `lblAnswer.Text = txtA.Text + txtB.Text' (which still would not work since you are concatenating two strings, not adding two numeric values). lbl and txt are also not good choice for Android widget prefixes. If I'm wrong, just ignore me. If I'm right, forget everything you know about VB GUI when coding Android and rejoice that Java has no concept of "default properties" :)

Comment: No Simon you are partially correct. I am actually coming from Action script with Adobe flash builder. It has been labeled as the best way to learn logic of android development before learning how to develop with eclipse. And I'm finding that this is so false. Eclipse and action scriptd edevelopment ls so different its rediculius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is missing a few key components. Review your code, and review the one I have prepared below.

```
package com.example.wattsprofessional;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText txtA, txtB;
    private Button button1;
// ^ we have declared these as fields up here so that we can access them throughout the page, past all the curly brackets

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtA = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtA);
        txtB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtB);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        // ^ this is where we initialize these. You did the xml correctly, but you still need to hook the java to it.
        // it allows us to use any names and locations we like not just same ones.
        // basically you say what it is (Button) and then use the following method to look for the id that you wrote in the xml

        initButton();
        // i made this listener so we'd have time. this is the oncreate method and is called instantly.
        // if we called doCalc here, we'd have no time to put numbers in.
    }

    private void initButton() {
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            // this one performs an action when our button is clicked. it performs whatever is below
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String strA = txtA.getText().toString();
                String strB = txtB.getText().toString();
                // we get our strings from our editexts. i think you know how to do this well.

                Double dblAnswer = doCalc(strA, strB);              
                // ^we pass them to our method, it does all the heavy lifting for us. and spits an answer for us.
                TextView lblAnswer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblAnswer);
                // this is a local variable, as opposed to a field. i made so you know that you can do it like this - with the whole line here
                // the disadvantage is that we can't do anything to it outside of this curly bracket. but there are performs gains.
                // in general it's wasteful to use fields when you can suffice with local variable
                String answer = String.valueOf(dblAnswer);
                // we get our answer and turn it to a string.
                lblAnswer.setText(answer);
                // finally we set our result to the textView.
            }
        });
    }

    public double doCalc(String a, String b) {
        // a and b are both variables. they refer to the stuff we put in
        double dblA = Double.parseDouble(a);
        double dblB = Double.parseDouble(b);
        // we're gonna make both of these numbers so we can add them. right now they're just text.
        return dblA + dblB;
        // ^ this statement means that this method will spit a number out when it's done which we can use however.
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you by far the best response . I agree I have lots of tutorials that I need to review. The details have helped tremendously.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get a Double value from an `EditText`, you'll need to use `Double.parseDouble(txtA.getText().toString())`. To set the text, you can use `lblAnswer.setText("text")`.

In addition, the easiest way to call this from a button would be to set its `android:onClick` attribute in the XML, such as `android:onClick="doCalc"`.

EDIT: You also need to create references to your objects. Before your onCreate(), put:

```
EditText txtA;
EditText txtB;
TextView lblAnswer;
```

Then inside your onCreate() you need to initialize the objects:

```
txtA = new (EditText)findViewById(R.Id.txtA);
txtB = new (EditText)findViewById(R.Id.txtB);
lblAnswer = new (TextView)findViewById(R.Id.lblAnswer);
```

Comment: Thank you Dare. I will go and try this right now. To second what you have stated here with the android:onClick. I have conducted this in the GUI is that the right place?

Comment: Yes, `android:onClick` is in the XML file for your GUI.

Comment: Alright, so I am a little confused with the above suggestion. What I am trying to do is create a calculated field. txtA + txtB will be the calculated fields for the lblAnswer?

Comment: Yes. The easiest way to do this is to create variables to hold the parsed values from the EditText, and then set the text to `Double.toString(num1+num2)` (assuming num1 and num2 are your variables).

Comment: Thank you Dare. I apologize but I am still learning and even this is a little confusing to me. I have provided my full code above in the revised edit. I will try to complete this code. but i am not too sure as to how to approach this still. I understand what I am supposed to do but do not know exactly how to do it if that makes since.

Comment: Your function doCalc() needs to take a View argument (eg.  `doCalc(View v)`) to be used with android:onClick. Also, you need to assign the result of Double.parseDouble to a variable, then add the variables.

Comment: Here is what I have changed.                                            `public void doCalc(View view) 
 {
  Double.parseDouble(txtA.getText().toString());
  Double.parseDouble(txtB.getText().toString());
  lblAnswer.setText("txtA + txtB")
 }`

Comment: That will only set the text of lblAnswer.setText to the string "txtA + txtB", you the value. You need to assign the parseDouble results to variables: `double num1 = Double.parseDouble(txtA.getText().toString())` and `double num2 = Double.parseDouble(txtB.getText().toString())`, then set lblAnswer.setText to the string of the sum: `lblAnswer.setText(Double.toString(num1 + num2))`

Comment: Thank you I just reconstructed the code to display what you have written here. for some reason txtA , txt B, and lblAnswer still has the error lines and still states (cannot be resolved). Here is what I have ..                                                                       `public void doCalc(View view) 
 {
  double num1 = Double.parseDouble(txtA.getText().toString());
  double num2 = Double.parseDouble(txtB.getText().toString());
  lblAnswer.setText(Double.toString(num1 + num2));
 }`

Comment: It is almost as if eclipse is not recognizing txt A, txt B, and lblAnswer as text fields.